# Magento 2 - How to call custom (Self Created) module in home page?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, custom

I have created a custom module with view using (Block, Layouts and Templates), its working fine with the url(http://hostname/modulename/index/test) but need to call it in home page. I mean when home page loaded, module should be rendering in home page in specific area with following fields (Name, age-group, gender etc.). And also have to save these fields values in database.

Steps followed during creation of module without view :

Step 1: Created the Namespace(CompanyName) and module(HelloWorld) folder

Step 2: Created etc/module.xml file

Step 3: Created etc/registration.php file

Step 4: Created etc/frontend/routes.xml file

Step 5: Created Controller/Index/Display.php

Steps followed during creation of module with view :

Step 1: Created layout - view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_display.xml

Step 2: Created block - app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/Block/Display.php

Step 3: Created template file - app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/sayhello.phtml

Everything is working fine just I have to render sayhello.phtml file in Homepage area. How I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: please provide more information regarding your module and what you have try.

Comment: I have created a custom module, its working fine with the url(http://host/modulename/index/test) but need to call it on home page. I mean when home page loaded, module should be called automatically.

Step 1: Created the Namespace and module folder
Step 2: Created etc/module.xml file
Step 3 : Created etc/registration.php file
Step 4 : Created etc/frontend/routes.xml file
Step 5 : Created Controller/Index/Test.php

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Is that for getting the data or rendering a view and then append to homepage ?

Comment: Yes, I want to rendering a view with following fields (Name, age-group, gender etc.) in homepage specific area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin panel, Content -> Pages -> Select Home Page (as per Store view) ->
here add

```
    {{block class="CompanyName\\HelloWorld\\Block\\Display" template="CompanyName_HelloWorld::sayhello.phtml"}}
```

This can help!!

Comment: Yes, Working. Thankyou :)

Comment: @MdAmanullah Please mark it as accepted solution so others also can get benefits.